# How to get equals and hashcode to work with Java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to learn Java RMI and I need to compare some objects. Specifically, I want to know if a set already contains an element, but it doesn't detect that an object is already present in the set. I don't have any other communication problems with RMI in general.

I've tried overriding `hashcode()` and `equals(Object obj)` in my remote object implementation, which is what I have to do from my understanding.

Here's some code:

```
public class ChatClientImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatClient {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3056117484716596895L;
    private String id = null;

    // some other stuff...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof ChatClientImpl)) {
            return false;
        }
        ChatClientImpl other = (ChatClientImpl) obj;
        return this.id.equals(other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id.hashCode();
    } 
}
```

`Set#contains` and `List#contains` just don't work. Is there some other trick to this?

Some more complete code:

```
public void processMessage(MessageImpl inMessage) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        // check the message to see if we have processed it before - discard if so
        if( this.processedMessages.contains(inMessage.id) ) {
            System.err.println("Ignoring duplicate message: " + inMessage.id);
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Processing message: " + inMessage.id);
            this.processedMessages.add(inMessage.id);
            System.out.println(this.processedMessages.size() + " messages have been processed");
        }
        // update the GUI display with the new message
        this.gui.updateDisplay(inMessage);

        // add this client to the set of clients that have seen the message
        inMessage.addRecipient(this);

        // pass the message on to one of the clients that haven't seen it yet
        sendMessage(inMessage);
    }

        private void sendMessage(MessageImpl msg) {
                Iterator<ChatClient> clientIterator;
                try {
                    // list of all known clients fetched from a server via RMI call
                    clientIterator = server.getClients().iterator();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // log the error...
                    return;
                }
                // clients that have already seen the message
                Set<ChatClient> alreadyPassedThru = msg.getRecipients(); 
                boolean messageSent = false;

                while ( ! messageSent && clientIterator.hasNext() ){
                    ChatClient knownClient = clientIterator.next();
                    try {
                        // clients that are in alreadyPassedThru are NOT detected...
                        if ( alreadyPassedThru.contains(knownClient) ){  
                            System.out.println("Skipping client that has already seen the message: " + knownClient.getName());
                        } else {
                            knownClient.processMessage(msg);
                            System.out.println("Message has been sent to " + knownClient.getName());
                            messageSent = true;
                        }
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // client couldn't be contacted
                        clientIterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It's worth mentioning that if I replace the code `if ( alreadyPassedThru.contains(knownClient) )` (which is where the problem is) with some code that iterates over the set `alreadyPassedThru` and manually checks if any of the elements match `knownClient` by comparing their respective `clientName` variables, then everything works fine.

The MessageImpl code:

```
public class MessageImpl implements java.io.Serializable, Message {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8914588083609635659L;

    /** 
     * The globally unique identifier for this message 
     */
    public final GUID id;

    /** 
     * All remote clients that have seen this message so far
     */
    public final Set<ChatClient> passedThrough = new HashSet<ChatClient>();

    /**
     * The content of the message. 
     */
    private String messageContent = null;

    /**
     * The client who created the object
     */
    private ChatClient author = null; 

    /** 
     * Create a new Message instance. 
     */
    public MessageImpl(ChatClient auth, String msg) {
        this.id = new GUID(auth);
        this.author = auth; 
        this.messageContent = msg; 
        addRecipient(auth); // the author has seen the message
    }

    @Override
    public void addRecipient(ChatClient client) {
        this.passedThrough.add(client);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ChatClient> getRecipients() {
        return this.passedThrough;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContent() {
        return this.messageContent; 
    }

    public String getSource() {
        try {
            return this.author.getName();   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "[Unknown User]";
        }
    }
}
```

Just to clarify the difference between when the application works and when it doesn't work: if I replace this:

```
if ( alreadyPassedThru.contains(knownClient) ){...
```

where `alreadyPassedThru` is a `HashSet<ChatClient>` and `knownClient` is a `ChatClient` with this code:

```
// RMI call on ChatClient - simply returns clientName field
String knownClientName = knownClient.getName();
for (ChatClient client : alreadyPassedThru) {
   if ( client.getName().equals(knownClientName) ){
       return true;
   }
}
```

...then it works.

Comment: You are just checking for id you need to test all  fields in object.

Comment: Even if I don't care about equality regarding those other fields?

Comment: No, you don't need to check anything other than ID if that's all you care about.

Comment: @Sagar as long as the implementation matches the contract of `equals`, it is up to the programmer/designer to decide the criteria to use for matching...

Comment: I am not used to working directly with RMI, but I bet it has something to do with `obj.getClass() != this.getClass()` clause. Maybe RMI is creating a subclass of `MyRemote` to work as Stub? I would go with `instanceof`.

Comment: This is your implementation class. When using RMI, the client won't use this class, but a stub class which implements `Message`. Therefore, the `instanceof`-based check will fail if you try to compare a `MessageImpl` with a stub for a remote `Message`, even though their `id` is the same (btw, you can't get the `id` from a stub, because it's a field, you need methods). Also, if the client then passes its stub back to the server, the server *might* get a stub to the local object, rather than an actual reference to it (but I need to check the specification for this).

Comment: @GiulioFranco `MessageImpl` is not a remote object.

Comment: @EJP what I'm saying is that RTF might be inadvertently comparing a `ChatClientImpl ` and a stub to that `ChatClientImpl ` for equality, and that comparison would fail, because the stub belongs to a different class. As he said, the "set for comparison is referencing the interface, not the implementation".

Comment: @GiuloFranco As `MessageImpl` is not a remote object, it doesn't have a stub. The object being compared is a `ChatClient.`

Comment: @EJP Sorry, replace `MessageImpl` with `ChatClientImpl`

Comment: @GiulioFranco When you read my answer you will see that remote objects and their stubs have the same hashcodes and `equals()` behaviour under a condtion which is satisfied by this code. See the Javadoc for `java.rmi.RemoteObject.`

Comment: @EJP Yes, unless, as you said, the methods are overriden. I was not countering your answer. I was just trying to explain what's happening here. I think your answer is correct, which is why I didn't re-post it.

Comment: @GiulioFranco You're just causing confusion. I had already stated what you now say you tried to state in about six attempts. BTW the stub the server receives is the stub the client sent. I don't know what you even mean by 'stub to the local object'.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `instanceof` instead of the `getClass()` method.

```
if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof MyRemote)) {
    ...
}
```

This is, at the very least, more efficient and may be the cause of your issue.

You might also want to consider simplifying your logic a bit. Right now, you have 3 return points in your code and the intent is not immediately clear. Try this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof MyRemoteImpl) {
        MyRemoteImpl other = (MyRemoteImpl) obj;
        return this.id.equals(other.id);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you're actually calling the equals (or contains) method?

Comment: As per the code you just posted, the call to contains should be returning false (as you say it is), as you never added the new instance to your HashSet.

Comment: sorry, just pseudocode. It will be in the set by the time the comparison is made. I'll try to post something more complete

Comment: Looking at your updated code. So, why are you checking for whether or not an object is an instance of ChatClientImpl in the equals method for class MyRemoteImpl?

Comment: ;) thats not the update, I accidentally put that in when I updated with the `instanceof` line. That's my actual class name, I've just been using MyRemote as a general example. I'll post something more complete in a few minutes, I'm just trying to filter out anything irrelevant to the issue to make it as easy as possible to understand

Comment: At this point, I can be fairly certain that your problem is not with your equals method implementation. Take a look at your design, run your code through a debugger, perhaps take my suggestions into mind and then come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: You don't need the null check with `instanceof.`

Answer (score 1):

They already work with Java RMI.

Remote objects and their stubs have the same hashcodes and equals() behaviour by default if the remote objects extend `UnicastRemoteObject.`

However you've broken that by overriding `hashCode()` and `equals().`

Just remove those overrides.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I was actually doing things that way originally and it was only later that I added in the overrides because I thought that was the correct way of doing it. I just want to mention again that if I replace the `Set#contains` method call with a manual check (by iterating over the set and comparing each element) then it can find the element it's looking for. So, the contains call is failing when it shouldn't be. I'm only assuming it's related to RMI because it seems most likely.

Comment: Please clarify what '`clientName` variable' you are checking manually, and how an interface can have a member variable, and whether your set is `Set<MyRemote>` or `Set<ChatClient>.`

Comment: Interestingly, the doc for `RemoteObject.equals` says "If the specified Object is not itself an instance of RemoteObject, then this method delegates by returning the result of invoking the equals method of its parameter with this remote object as the argument.". So overriding in itself should not break things.

Comment: Things broke because `equals` is checking for the concrete class type. But still, removing the overrides should work, unless there are multiple `ChatClientImpl` instances with the same name.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Removig the override will work regardless. The default implementation doesn't care or even know about the name field. It just works on the remote object ID. I suspect the OP has another problem, or still hasn't removed the overrides.

Comment: @EJP if the overrides are removed, then `equals` checks for identity (i.e. checks if the passed object has the same address OR is a stub referring to that same object). If two different servers exists which have the same name (which would imho be a bug), then the default `equals` would return `false`, even though the two are logically equivalent, because they are not the same instance.

Comment: @GiulioFranco I repeat. The hashcode and equality are computed by default over the remote object ID. That does not contain the instance name, whatever that is, and it consists of a great deal more than the server name, or whatever you're talking about now. That's enough guesswork, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75075/discussion-between-giulio-franco-and-ejp).

Comment: @Giulio No thanks. You've caused quite enough confusion here already.

Comment: @EJP for the record, you're right. I know you know, But I think it's appropriate to clarify.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Of course it's appropriate to clarify. What isn't appropriate is to cause confusion, and get the class name wrong, the semantics, change your mind, ... all in half a dozen messages which add exactly nothing to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as follows:

```
public class ChatClientImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatClient {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3056117484716596895L;
    private String id = null;

    // some other stuff...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (super.equals(obj)) {
            //Should also return true for stubs pointing to this
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof ChatClient)) { //Check against the interface
            return false;
        }
        //Only use the interface. obj might be a stub, not only an impl.
        ChatClient other = (ChatClient) obj;
        return getName().equals(obj.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    } 
}
```

I am definitely not sure this will work, but the specification for `RemoteObject.equals` makes me hope so.

#### EDIT

This can't work, because `equals` and `hashCode` are computed directly on the stub, regardless of what you implemented on your server.

This leaves you with two options:

1. (which I suggest) rely on the default equals. The client ID should be unique, and there should be no two clients with the same ID. That's clearly not the case in your implementation, because you're using an additional `id` field, implying the identity of an instance is not enough. I think it should be.
2. Wrap your `ChatClient`s in a `CustomHashChatClient` and use a `Set<CustomHashChatClient>`, with `CustomHashChatClient` computing a custom hash, based on the object name, id, or whatever you want (of course, you need to swallow the exceptions or fail on them, which makes this a not-so-good idea).

Comment: I had to wrap the `getName` calls in try catch blocks because they throw `RemoteException` and I can't modify the method definitions by throwing. Anyway, it didn't work.

Comment: @RTF yes. It's a design limitation of Java to improve the performance of hash-based collections and compute hashes and equality without the complications of a remote call. I added some workarounds to my answer.